# Button won't work in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

When I build the project and the window is created, for some reason I can't get the button to depress... and it won't recognize the code behind click event neither... any ideas?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Add / Edit">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Name="addeditBtn" Click="Add_Edit_Click">A/E</Button>
             </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Account_Name].Value}" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Income" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Income].Value}" />                    
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**UPDATE: I figured it out. Seems I had a got_focus event that was taking precedence over this event...**

Comment: <Button Name="addeditBtn" Click="Add_Edit_Click">A/E</Button> do you have an actual Event with code behind in your C# code not the xaml code that you can post...??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an Event Handler for your Button addeditBtn. So in your Code Behind page, create the C# code that will handle the click event of the button. Have you created this code? If so, please post it so that we can get a look at the code.